# Create an image from a Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am looking at a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base

# Install the SSHD server
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
  && mkdir -p /run/sshd \
  && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd
#Copy settings file. See elsewhere to find them. 
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
COPY authorized_keys  root/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Install Visual Studio Remote Debugger
RUN apt-get install zip unzip
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg
  
EXPOSE 2222
```

I am trying to create an image using this dockerfile.  How can I do this? I have read many webpages over the last few hours e.g. this one https://odewahn.github.io/docker-jumpstart/building-images-with-dockerfiles.html, however they all seem to overcomplicate it as I believe that there is only one command needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have a Docker file, you are required to do 4 additional steps:

1. `docker build -t <app-name> .` : Building your image
2. `docker images` : Check your image
3. `docker run -d -p 2222:8080 myapp` : Run your image
4. `docker ps` : Check running docker image

Refer [Docker doc.](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) for more detials

Comment: what about Kubernetes.  How would I run it in Kubernetes?

Comment: That would be an entire new question. You might want to create `docker-compose` for your `Dockerfile` and then translate your `docker-compose` to a Kubernetes resource.

Comment: OK.  I have asked another question here is you would like to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60935479/why-is-kubectl-looking-for-a-local-image-on-the-internet

Answer (score 1):

If `Dockerfile` is in your current directory, this command will build image and store it locally:

```
docker build -t "app:latest" .
```

[Here is documentation for `build` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

Then you can run it in background with:

```
docker run -d -p 2222:2222 app
```

This command will create container and start it. [Here is documentation for `run` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you consider 'overcomplicated' on that website?

There's one command on that site that says `docker build -t "simple_flask:dockerfile" .`. The only complication is that it adds a tag, which is explained directly underneath it

The only thing that might be simpler is not tagging it. so you do

```
docker build .
```

which means: build me an image. from the current directory.

Comment: Should I be able to run the following command after I have created the image? kubectl run my-app --image=myApp --port=5000.  It appears to be looking for myApp in DockerHub.

Comment: I cannot believe how difficult this is.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @w0051977 Do you use minikube to run k8s?