# Why is Kubectl looking for a local image on the Internet?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Please see my images below:

[image]

I then run this:

```
kubectl run my-app --image=iansimage:latest --port=5000
```

and this:

```
kubectl expose deployment my-app --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 --target-port=5000
```

However, I then see this:

[image]

Notice the warning in the above screenshot: "Error response from daemon: pull access denied for iansimage, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied".

Why is Kubectl trying to find iansimage:latest  on the internet? iansimage:latest  is a local image I created as per my last question: [Create an image from a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60932424/create-an-image-from-a-dockerfile/60932772?noredirect=1#comment107806770_60932772)

Please note that I am new to Kubernetes so this may be simple?

**Update**

Following on from Burak Serdars's comment.  Say I have a com,and like this, which would nomally build an image: `docker build -t "app:latest" .`

How would I build this image inside a Kubernetes pod?

Comment: The image has to be in the node's local docker storage.

Comment: where is your k8s cluster placed ? cloud or minikube?

Comment: @Fauzan, I have enabled kubernetes in docker desktop.

Comment: @Buraj Serder, is that not the case here?

Comment: Then @BurakSerdar is right. you need to find which docker storage that used by kubernetes worker node.

Comment: @Fauzan, are you able to elaborate or post an answer? I am new to kubernetes.  Thanks.

Comment: @Burak Serdar, are you able to look at the update to my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Latest" is a special tag, it means that Docker always check if the downloaded image is the latest available searching the registry. 
Retag your image with other tag than latest, like this :

> docker tag iansimage:latest iansimage:v1

Then change your Yaml and use iansimage:v1
That solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use kubectl run I believe it will create a deployment resource with a member named ImagePullPolicy which I believe defaults to `Always`.  You might be able to change this with `kubectl edit deployment my-app` to set this field to `IfNotPresent`.

You might also consider @Enzo's suggestion to tag the image to a particular version.